# Is there a way to allow access to PHP scripts on a .htaccess password protected directory from Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, .htaccess

I am working on a project that is sensitive and needs to be protected with a .htaccess password before launch.

It is a game that required information from PHP which is hosted on this protected server, and at the moment I need to upload the SWF every time I make a change that I want to test which is extremely time consuming, because compiling it of course gives me an error like the below:

> Error opening URL 'http://site.com/script.php'

Is there a way (maybe through one of the Security related classes) that I can send the .htaccess username and password up with the request to get the information I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question very well but :
Did you try to allow your ip in the .htaccess file like this...

```
<Files page.php>
AuthName "Your stuff here" 
deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>
```

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your IP ???

Answer (score 0):

what if you write a simple local script and send your request to it instead to the remote server. Then in that local php script implement the real request to the protected server by using curl. I'm saying that because if you use curl you can send username and password. Example here http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-sending-username-password/